# Firebase Forge with large datasets

Tags: firebase, forge

My Company is starting to use Firebase for some of our commercial products, and so far we are very satisfied with the product. We do however have one issue, which is the Forge UI.

It is extremely slow on big data sets, as it loads the entire firebase into the DOM. I am guessing it wont even work if we get to several hundred MB of data.

Is there a plan to implement some kind of "pagination" to the Forge UI?

Have any other firebase users found a way around this issue?

Answer (score 4):

A simple workaround is to load Forge by using a more specific URL instead of trying to load the root data set.

For example, if my Firebase is `kato`, instead of visiting `https://kato.firebaseio.com`, I can visit `https://kato.firebaseio.com/widgets/red`.

There are some Forge improvements in the works to help with large data sets. I'm not sure where they are on the road map.